# Nginx don`t use cache after url rewrite

Tags: nginx

I want to use nginx as internet out proxy.
So, I try to connect to http://mirror01.org/google.com, but cache files were not created.
If I delete rewrite rule and replace proxy_pass to http://google.come cache files will be created.

Where did I go wrong?

Trace using curl

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.20.2
Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2022 15:44:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 145
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://google.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2022 15:44:42 GMT
Expires: Thu, 07 Apr 2022 15:44:42 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2022 15:44:43 GMT
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: Tue, 08 Mar 2022 15:44:43 GMT
Cache-Control: private
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2022-03-08-15; expires=Thu, 07-Apr-2022 15:44:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure
Set-Cookie: NID=511=21PQ3ziwDTFTppHDMUoAVReBsFB6oGkVHqT38eqJO25UQkP3SJSEleOsHhefVDR_TgKSK6DpcTmBewjKC-kazv8mWRrfW10NUJevh16H5MZtKrKCJxllfI4r; expires=Wed, 07-Sep-2022 15:44:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
```

Nginx conf:

```
access_log /opt/nginx/log/access.log main;
error_log /opt/nginx/log/error.log crit;

proxy_cache_path /opt/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=default_cache:10m max_size=2g
                 inactive=120m use_temp_path=off;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
proxy_cache_valid any 60m;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  mirror01.org;

    location / {
        proxy_cache default_cache;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires;
        proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
        proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;

        proxy_hide_header X-Accel-Expires;
        proxy_hide_header Expires;
        proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
        proxy_hide_header Pragma;

        add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass $request_uri;
    }
}
```